# SwiftUI .rotationEffect() issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have to create this cross background
here is my code

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJGnz.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUE6n.png)

```
ZStack {
      Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
      HStack {
        Rectangle()
         .foregroundColor(.clear)
         .background(viewModel.pageColors[viewModel.currentPageIndex])
         .ignoresSafeArea()
         .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.65,maxHeight: .infinity)
                //         .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 8.44))
        Rectangle()
          .foregroundColor(.clear)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
      .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach it's quite simple and optimised

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width * 0.35, y: geometry.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width * 0.65, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geometry.size.height))
        path.closeSubpath()
    }.fill(.green)
}.ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: This will give a different angle of slope depending on the device dimensions and orientation.

Comment: @BenzyNeez yes it will be dynamic according to device's size but the angle of slope will remain same for all

Comment: The angle of slope will depend on the height of the device. So two devices with the same width but different heights will have different angles of slope. And when you turn the device to landscape, it is different again. In fact, when I tried your code it gave a sort of X-star instead of a clean diagonal. Goodness knows why this was chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more convenient to just create your custom `Shape` than to rotate rectangles around.

```
struct RectangleWithSlantedEdge: Shape {
    let angle: Angle
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: rect.origin)
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - rect.height * tan(angle.radians), y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

```
ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Color.black
        RectangleWithSlantedEdge(angle: .degrees(8.8))
            .fill(.yellow)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.65)
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Note that the `angle` here is the angle that the slanted edge makes with a vertical line.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I was trying to solve it by scaling the rotated rectangle, but it didn't work reliably if the orientation was changed on a tall device (so I deleted the answer). This is a safer approach and should be the accepted solution.